# Writing a method to find the prime factors of a number

Tags: methods, .net-5, prime-factoring, c#-9.0

It's my first time creating a method in a class library to be used in a console app.

I'm trying to return a list of all prime factors of a number that is input
(Examples: if I input 4 it should return 2 and 4; input 50 it should return 2, 5, and 5).

Here's what I have for the method:

```cs
namespace PrimeFactorsLib
{
    public class PrimeFactorsClass
    {
        public string PrimeFactors(int a, byte b)
        {
            string x = "";
            for (b =2; a > 0; b++)
            {
                while (a % b == 0)
                {
                    x = "{b}";
                }
            }

            return x;
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting that x, and you will get stuck in the while loop because the condition never changes

Comment: Why does your code return a string rather than a list of ints? Why does the method take two arguments? Why is your loop condition `a>0` when `a` never changes?

Comment: The first example doesn't make sense, 4 is not a prime factor.

Comment: @Tony D, you can check at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/. There you'll find an efficient code to get the prime factors of a given number. This site shares the code in many programming languages (C++, Java, Python, PHP); C# is also included. I suggest you use www.geeksforgeeks.org as a learning resource. There you can get the code and include it in your method...

Comment: This is a reasonably well formulated question in that you state the goal and show what you've tried. But it'd be a lot easier to respond to if you explicitly stated what the results of your code are. Presumably, it's not giving you the expected output, so providing some examples of what the actual output is would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of combining your code with the one in GeeksForGeeks as I wrote in the previous comment:

```
    namespace PrimeFactorsLib
    {
      public class PrimeFactorsClass
      {
    
        public string primeFactors(int n)
        {
            string x = "";
            // Print the number of 2s that divide n
            while (n % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write(2 + " ");
                n /= 2;
            }
     
            // n must be odd at this point. So we can
            // skip one element (Note i = i +2)
            for (int i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(n); i+= 2)
            {
                // While i divides n, print i and divide n
                while (n % i == 0)
                {
                    x += "{i} ";
                    n /= i;
                }
            }
     
            // This condition is to handle the case when
            // n is a prime number greater than 2
            x += "{n}";
        }
        return x;
      }
    }
```

Try this and see if it's the result you're looking for. Anyway, there is another, more efficient algorithm that you can also combine in your code. You can check this one at [Prime Factorization using Sieve O(log n) for multiple queries](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/).